# How to get rozer pay all payment information using transaction_id

Tags: android

```
public class RozerPaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentResultListener, RequestService.RequestServiceListener {

    private AutoReadOtpHelper autoReadOtpHelper; // Declare the receiver instance as a member variable

    private Button pay;
    public String result, name, email, phone, amount;
    SwitchCompat mode;

    public static TicketInterface mListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rozer_pay_payment);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        phone = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
        amount = intent.getStringExtra("amount");

        if (name == null || email == null || phone == null || amount == null) {
            // Handle null values or missing extras
            // Show an error message or perform appropriate actions
            if (name == null) {
                Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "Null value for 'name' received from Intent");
            }
            if (email == null) {
                Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "Null value for 'email' received from Intent");
            }
            if (phone == null) {
                Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "Null value for 'phone' received from Intent");
            }
            if (amount == null) {
                Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "Null value for 'amount' received from Intent");
            }
            return;
        }

        registerReceiver();

        Checkout.preload(getApplicationContext());

        final String merName = name;
        final String urPhone = phone;
        final String urEmail = email;

        try {
            int payAmount = Integer.parseInt(amount) * 100;
            final String pay = String.valueOf(payAmount);

            Checkout checkout = new Checkout();
            checkout.setKeyID("rzp_test_ngHXz5sYhFdHAH");

            /**
             * Set your logo here
             */
            checkout.setImage(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);

            /**
             * Reference to current activity.
             **/
            final Activity activity = RozerPaymentActivity.this;

            /**
             * Pass your payment options to the Razorpay Checkout as a JSONObject
             */
            JSONObject options = new JSONObject();

            options.put("name", merName);
            options.put("description", "Reference No. #654321");
            options.put("image", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rzp-mobile/images/rzp.png");
            options.put("theme.color", "#3399cc");
            options.put("currency", "INR");
            options.put("amount", pay);
            options.put("prefill.email", urEmail);
            options.put("prefill.contact", urPhone);
            JSONObject retryObj = new JSONObject();
            retryObj.put("enabled", true);
            retryObj.put("max_count", 4);
            options.put("retry", retryObj);

            checkout.open(activity, options);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "Error in starting Razorpay Checkout", e);
            // Handle the exception or show an error message
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
      
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String result) {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                PopupDialog.getInstance(RozerPaymentActivity.this)
                        .setStyle(Styles.SUCCESS)
                        .setHeading("Well Done")
                        .setDescription(result)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .showDialog(new OnDialogButtonClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDismissClicked(Dialog dialog) {
                                super.onDismissClicked(dialog);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle the exception or show an error message
            Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "Error in showing dialog", e);
        }
    }

    // Register the receiver
    private void registerReceiver() {
        autoReadOtpHelper = new AutoReadOtpHelper(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        registerReceiver(autoReadOtpHelper, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mListener = null;
        if (autoReadOtpHelper != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(autoReadOtpHelper);
            autoReadOtpHelper = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String error) {
        Log.e("RozerPaymentActivity", "API error: " + error);
    }
```

This is my class using this i am  able to do rozer_pay payment in test mode and also i am able to get call back when payment success or fail in onPaymentSuccess and onPaymentError but what i am trying to get i want to know complete payment information  like  due to some issue payment deduct or payment is in refund process or anything  i am not  able to find how i can fetch those information . i have google it i found  using this API we can get information [https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/[Payment_id](https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/%5BPayment_id) =pay_MAyKoqxJ2f6tz1] but when i try to access this one its asking login and password in browser can any one help me in this.

Thanks

```
}
```